I ran into a problem with the texture paint feature
I’m sculpting a character right now and I’m at the point where i started coloring/texture painting it. All was going well until at one point blender wouldn’t let me texture paint it anymore. An error pops up at the bottom of the screen saying Missing Materials, Textures, detected!.
I’ve searched up what this means and didn’t really get anywhere. I also created a whole new project and the same problem happens in it. When I’m in viewport shading mode the object that I want to texture paint turns purple.
Now it’s looks like I can no longer texture paint in my Blender anymore.




Blender has lost the path to your image texture, go into File > External Data > Find Missing Files and search for the image

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Pink indicates a missing texture. You cannot paint the texture because there isnt any texture to paint! You can select the Eye-Material and assign a new texture; You do that by going to the Shading-Tab on top of the window, and then hook up a new texture node, and create a texture. You need to save the texture! Or it will be lost. You do that in the Image Viewer or Image Editor by selecting Image->Save or Save As


